# The concept of django admin when adding information with foreign keys

Tags: django, django-admin

I really can't find the right words to Google this so I am here to find help. I want to use the idea of the admin page in django where when you add an information and it has a foreign key, a plus sign is present beside the field and with that, you can add data that pops up in a new window and after saving, the new data automatically reflects the selection.

---

Okay. I solved the add button. Now what I want is the data will appear after saving in the select drop down. I haven't had the answer to it yet

Comment: Okay. I solved the add button. Now what I want is the data will appear after saving in the select drop down. I haven't had the answer to it yet

Answer (score 0):

This is easy, if even the other model(which is your foreign key) is added to the Admin. It directly shows the plus button. But, if you don't want that.

I guess you are searching for [InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).

Comment: Okay. I solved the add button. Now what I want is the data will appear after saving in the select drop down. I haven't had the answer to it yet